# Nginx multiple server blocks listening to same port

Tags: nginx

I want to run `www.example.com` and `api.example.com` on same port `80`.

This is what I have. All my googles ping lead to the below code. But, this is not working.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/example.com/html/example/app;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name www.example.com www.example.org;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /bower_components {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/bower_components;
        }

        location /scripts {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/scripts;
        }

        location /content {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/content;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3836;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80
        server_name api.example.com

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3836;
        }
}
```

I do not know the reason. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: The root dir is missing in the `api.example.com` virtual host.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create separately two files (you don't have to, but it will be much clearer) in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.example.com`

The api.example.com file's content:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com;
        root /var/www/api.example.com/html/example/app; #also add a root dir here
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3836;
        }
}
```

The www.example.com's content:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/example.com/html/example/app;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name www.example.com www.example.org;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /bower_components {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/bower_components;
        }

        location /scripts {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/scripts;
        }

        location /content {
                alias /var/www/example.com/html/example/content;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3836;
        }
}
```

And finally enable the domains:
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.example.com` and `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.example.com`

Comment: I am not able to understand what do you mean by "Also add the www.example.com virtual host to you config file:". Could you explain more?

Comment: If this doesn't work what is the output of the `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` command if you try to reach the webpage?

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorted it out.

Comment: -1 This just a convenience. You don't have to separate servers blocks in multiple files, and it doesn't solve any configuration issues you'd have except any problems due to nginx loading the confs in the wrong order (which you are at least as likely to cause).

Comment: I found when I tried this, that nginx just chose the default_server and ignored the other one. not sure why

Comment: @TravisGriggs I can't say with 100% certainty but I'd hazard a guess that your API client needs to send a 'Host' header with the correct value that will let nginx differentiate between the www and api server blocks.

Answer (score 4):

The initial questioned config was missing semicolons at the end of the lines for listen and server_name. This could cause it to not be read.