# Running Nginx on Raspberry Pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to run a Node server on a Raspberry Pi. Full disclosure: I have no knowledge of servers, I am an interface designer and developer, so command lines are an unknown to me, don't expect prior knowledge.

I tried to follow many instructions on installing Nginx, but now it fails and I can't it to point to a line where I could check where it fails.

```
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

The `journalctl -xn` says there is no file, and the other one gives me details, but I cant make heads or tails of it:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-07-07 12:43:36 EDT; 38s ago
  Process: 1071 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I followed an instruction where it said that it's best to copy the `sites-available/default` rather than edit it, and here is what I did:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/osc-api/www;

  index index.html; 

  server_name _;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name osc-api;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

And yes, it is symlinked to the `sites-enabled`. I guess I am looking for info on how to understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please verify that port 80 is not used by apache or some other process.

Comment: @AtulAgrawal I do I check that? There is actually nothing else than Nginx on the Pi at this time. Your comments makes me think: is it possible that the two server block require a different port?

Comment: @AtulAgrawal That seems to be correct, I needed a different port per `server {}` block. Does that sound good enough to you?

Comment: You don't really need that until your server name is different.The point is there any other process which is consuming port 80?

Comment: This surely help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055212/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-listening-to-same-port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that port 80 is not used by apache or some other process.
Please see this link
[Nginx multiple server blocks listening to same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055212/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-listening-to-same-port)