# Configure Nginx to manage multiple servers with the same port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

given this Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8443;
    ssl on;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Web Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://serverA;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Which is basically redirecting every request made towards the `https://nginxIP:8443` to `http://serverA`, is it possible to obtain a configuration so that:

- https://nginxIP:8443/serverA/ points to http://serverA;
- https://nginxIP:8443/serverB/ points to http://serverB;

And so on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33055212/1135424

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second `location` to redirect your requests.

```
location /serverA/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://serverA/;
    ...
}

location /serverB/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://serverB/;
    ...
}
```

**update:** the trailing slash at `proxy_pass` is important to avoid adding the location path.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but if I open https://nginxIP:8443/serverA I'm receiving a 404 from serverA; I think Nginx is redirecting me to http://serverA/serverA

Comment: Sorry. You're right, I updated my previous post because I forgot to add trailing slashes to the proxies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This improved the script in the sense that now it seems that Nginx is forwarding the requests for https://nginxIP:8443/serverB/ to http://serverB/, but the website is doing a redirect to https://nginxIP:8443/app/ while it should be https://nginxIP:8443/serverB/app. There is something else missing in the configuration :(

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem because location redirects to every destination you want it to. Maybe the documentation can give you the right hint: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: I'm checing documentation and tutorials but I'm stuck with this issue because probably there is something I haven't considered yet. In my opinion (but I could be wrong) the fact is that when pointing to https://nginxIP:8443/serverA/ the server is somehow redirecting towards http://serverB/some_uri while it should be https://nginxIP:8443/serverA/some_uri. Is it possible to handle this with Nginx?

Comment: Please update your question with the current state otherwise it's hard to follow.