# how to fix nginx multiple domains SSL error

Tags: ssl, nginx, devops, lets-encrypt, nginx-config

I have 2 domains and my nginx configuration is as below. When I type example.com, website is opening with ssl without any problem but if I type example.nl browser gives "Your connection is not private" warning.

I tested both domains certificates by changing configuration and both worked without problem separately.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

```
upstream website {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;
    server_name *.example.com *.example.nl;


    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    # serve static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    # serve media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /media/;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://ourwebsite;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.example.nl;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.nl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.nl/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    # serve static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    # serve media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /media/;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://website;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding as another site in available sites, rather than another server in the same site?

Comment: Have a look at this link here for an example. I think nginx will use whatever is defined last https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055212/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-listening-to-same-port

Comment: I am running nginx in docker contain, I checked sites-available folder in etc, it does not exist.

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available/

Comment: Yes, I checked same directory. I think I should be able to solve this problem with single configuration file. They said separating configuration files is just a convention in the question above.

Comment: Where are you finding the config above? Why would you not follow a convention when you are having an issue.

Comment: My config is in etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf. I think problem is not convention but I will try.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: your names don't match**

You have `server{}` blocks for SSL with `server_name` values `*.example.com` and `*.example.nl` but you are making requests for `example.com` and `example.nl`. These do not match either of the server blocks. A DNS wildcard like `*.example.com` matches *any* value in that label (`abc.example.com` or `wazoo.example.com` or `oompapaoompapaoompapa.example.com`) but it does not match a name with *no* such label like `example.com`. You may be confusing it with a shell 'glob' or regular expression (such as sed, awk, perl, etc.) where `*` is the 'Kleene star' with zero-or-more semantics.

Since your requests don't match either server block, nginx uses the default server block; since you didn't specify a default block explicitly, nginx makes it the first. The first SSL server block uses the certificate for `example.com` so the request to `example.com` matches that certificate and works, while the request to `example.nl` does not match and fails. If you configure *only* the `*.example.nl` block, it is now the first and thus the default, and so requests to `example.nl` work but requests to `example.com` fail.

Change your server_name's to be, or include, a match for the actual names you use.