# Nginx reverse proxy - config for subdomain

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, vps

- Hi everyone, I am using vps ubuntu of amazon ec2 for my porject. I
  have 3 project on my vps, they are build on nodejs, so I run it with
  3 port: 3000 and 3001 and 80.
- I bought a domain in godaddy, the url like: abc.def, now, when I go to browser and type
  **abc.def:3000**, **abc.def:3001**, **abc.def**, it run ok with 3 projects above.

  ### The question is

  How I can config it to when I type
- **abc.def** -> it run project port 3000
- **site.abc.def** -> it run portject port 3001
- **site2.abc.def** -> it run portject port 80

Thank for your comment here

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 sub-domains (site.abc.def and site2.abc.def) and create a nginx configuration file with all the 3 domains with different server directives for each site. Use proxy_pass and direct it as per your requirement.

Edit:
Something similar as in the following answer [Nginx multiple server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055212/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-listening-to-same-port)

Comment: Thank karikevinod, let me try it. Do you know how diff between sites-available and sites-enabled?

Comment: Sites enabled is the symbolic link of the files in the sites available. It's there in the link provided with above link.

Comment: Thank karikevinod, I configured it successfully, the new question of me is now, in project 1, when i type project1.abc.def -> it goto localhost:3000 (OK), but when I type project1.abc.def:3000, it stills goto localhost:3000 (That I dont want to), I see some tip on google that using 
"port_in_redirect off;"
" proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;"

I tried it but not working